# Yii2 custom template for input field

Tags: php, html, yii2

This is my code I want to add template for input field which is not proper what i want:

```
<?=$form->field($modelSignupSlotDates, 'SlotDate',
[
    'template' => "<div class='col-md-2'><div class='form-group date'>{input}</div></div>",'options'=>['class'=>'form-group']
    ])->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'name'=>"SignupSlotDates[SlotDate]",
        'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t($messageFile,'SignupExpirationDatePlaceholderText'), 'autocomplete' => 'off'],
        'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
        'removeButton' => false,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose'=>true,
            'format' => 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            'startDate' => date('m-d-Y'),
            'endDate' => date('m-d-Y', strtotime('+60 days')),
        ]
    ])->label(false);?>
```

And Below is the HTML what I'm getting:

```
<div class="form-group field-signupslotdates-slotdate">
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="form-group date">
    <div id="signupslotdates-slotdate-kvdate" class="input-group date">
        <input id="signupslotdates-slotdate" class="krajee-datepicker form-control" name="SignupSlotDates[SlotDate]" placeholder="Expiration date" autocomplete="off" data-datepicker-source="signupslotdates-slotdate-kvdate" data-datepicker-type="3" data-krajee-kvdatepicker="kvDatepicker_26ee0803" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-addon kv-date-calendar" title="Select date">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I want Below Structure, which i'm not able to do.

```
<div class='col-md-2'><div class='form-group date'>
    <input class="krajee-datepicker form-control" name="" placeholder="Date" type="text">
    <span class='input-group-addon kv-date-calendar' title='Select date'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></i></span>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The problem in `<div id="signupslotdates-slotdate-kvdate" class="input-group date">` wrapper, right?
You no need this wrapper?